# Content Version update using Before Insert or Update Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Isn't it possible to update Content Version using `Before Insert or Update` trigger.

I have to update tags for a Content Version. PFB the code.But it is not working somehow. I am not even getting any error. Can someone suggest how this can be fixed.

```
trigger ContentTrg on ContentVersion (Before Insert, Before Update) {
  for(ContentVersion conObj : Trigger.New){
    // If(conObj.TagCsv != null)
     {  SYSTEM.DEBUG('############ conObj.TagCsv ' + conObj.TagCsv + ' Business_Model ' + conObj.Business_Model__c);
           if(conObj.Business_Model__c != null)
            conObj.TagCsv += ', ' + conObj.Business_Model__c ;
           if(conObj.Account__r.Geo_HDS__c != null)
            conObj.TagCsv += ', ' + conObj.Account__r.GEO_HDS__c;

           SYSTEM.DEBUG('############ conObj.TagCsv ' + conObj.TagCsv);
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: I can't find any error in your code. Are you sure the Business_Model__c and Account__r.Geo_HDS__c fields are not equal to null?

Comment: Yes, I can see the data appearing in last line of code in debug statement. But it is not updating on the content tag.

Comment: Do you have several triggers on ContentVersion? Could it be possible that another trigger updates this field after this trigger?

Comment: No this is only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is due the following reason "*Values for the `TagCsv` and `VersionData` fields are only available in triggers if the request to create or update ContentVersion records **originates from the API**.*"

Salesforce link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm